# python: How to concat horizontally two xls file with one column each into one xls file with 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, xlsx, xls

I have one file called input1.xls with one column and an another called input2.xls with one column. I want to get a file called output.xls with 2 columns and no index (I noticed that whether i set ignore_index to True or False i always get index in my output.xls file).
If possible i want to insert a header(letter, number) in the output.xls file as shown below

```
input1.xls  input2.xls 
  
a           1
b           2
c           3
d           4

output.xls

letter   number
a           1
b           2
c           3
d           4

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('input1.xls')
df2 = pd.read_csv('input2.xls')

(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True).to_csv('out.xls'))
```

Comment: Did you try my answer to solve the issue?

Comment: yes but with to_excel not with to_csv thank you very much

Comment: Whatever you use `to_excel` or `to_csv`, it works the same. If you have any further questions, please let me know, or It would be appreciate if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.columns`, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    0: [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

output = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
output.columns = ['letter', 'number']  # to add column names
output.to_csv('out.xls', index=False)
```

When I opened the file with MS Excel, it looks like:

[image]